# Weird viewing in Citrix Receiver (ATI card)

Tags: citrix

In a Ubuntu Natty desktop PC I connect to a MS Windows machine via Citrix Receiver, sometimes window looks weird (has blank areas, yo have to switch to another window outside citrix and come back to see it right). I tried wfcmgr changing window color settings but no luck. I think it's related with graphics card (ATI), changing to Ubuntu classic with no effects (no Unity, no Compiz) solves the problem but I don't want to stay in Ubuntu classic.

Now i'm using Unity 2D and works fine for me so seems a compiz related problem.

Answer (score 2):

I admin a Citrix farm at work, and I do connect via Citrix ICA back to work via my Linux box, however I have not seen the issue you are mentioning, but I am using an Nvidia card. Are you using the current version of the Citrix reciever (version 11)?

I did come across this page on the Citrix support site which has some troubleshooting steps for display issues using the Linux client, so perhaps it would be worth a read: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/receiver-linux-blackfoot/linux-troubleshooting-known-issues-display.html

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you, or an ATI powered machine handy to test with, but perhaps this will point you in the right direction.